# How to get incoming Bluetooth file or its path in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

What is the intent filter for BroadcastReceiver to get Bluetooth incoming file?

Actually I want to check received XML files and then want use them to import some data to my application.